# Joining two meshes into one

Tags: c++, mesh, cgal, cg, assimp

Suppose I have two meshes stored in any sane format (e.g. wavefront .obj or collada .dae), and I want to combine them into one mesh programmatically. More precise, I have a landscape and an object as two meshes. I want to put object into landscape after performing transformation to it, so it gets on the right place, and export this as result model.

As far as I understood, in **assimp** there is something similar named `SceneCombiner`, yet it seems that this is internal structure and has no interface (even though here https://github.com/assimp/assimp/issues/584 the ticket concerning it is closed, I couldn't find out how to use it).

Maybe I should use CGAL or something like that? I don't have very much experience in CG libraries, so any advice will be really useful!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that with CGAL.  You would read two meshes, and the call [copy_face_graph()](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/BGL/group__PkgBGLHelperFct.html#ga05c3459e1156362d21e5dac1d7a66a73), and then write the mesh back.

Comment: Thanks! I will try it a shot!